# Encontrar 6 números seguidos de una barra '/' y con un numero después con Regex en Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, regex

estaría necesitando ayuda en cuanto a expresiones regulares en Python.
El problema es que necesito encontrar un patrón como el siguiente ejemplo :

LOTE:  123456/1

La palabra 'LOTE:' seguida de un espacio luego 6 números enteros, luego una barra '/' y luego al final un numero entero.
Estoy utilizando la función search() de la librería re en python, el texto puede estar defectuoso debido a que es texto que se extrae de una imagen con un OCR, por eso puedo encontrarme con buscar ese patrón sobre algo así:

asdLOTE: ' 123456 /1

El regex que utilizo actualmente es el siguiente: search( r'LOTE:([0-9,/ ]*)', text, re.M|re.I) el cual no me esta dando buenos resultados.
Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano, saludos!

Comment: porque no usas el split

Comment: codigo = "asdLOTE:  123456/1"

Comment: split = codigo.split("/")

Comment: salida: ['asdLOTE:  123456', '1']

Comment: split2=split[0].split(" ")

Comment: print(split2[2]).....finalmente tendrias: 123456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independientemente del lenguaje, una expresión que te funcionaría para localizar ejemplos como el que pones sería:

```js
/LOTE:[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]*[0-9]{6}[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]*\/[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]*[0-9]{1}/g
```

https://regexr.com/40bda

Paso a paso:

- **LOTE:**                  => Literal
- **[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]***        => Busca la existencia (o no) de cualquier carácter que no sea una letra o un número
- **[0-9]{6}**               => Busca 6 dígitos consecutivos
- **[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]***        => Busca la existencia (o no) de cualquier carácter que no sea una letra o un número
- **/**                     => La barra (escapada)
- **[0-9]{6}**               => Busca 6 dígitos consecutivos
- **[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]***        => Busca la existencia (o no) de cualquier carácter que no sea una letra o un número
- **[0-9]{6}**               => Busca 6 dígitos consecutivos

Aunque en este caso (imagino que es un ejemplo de OCR, como comentas) nos encontramos "ruido" entre LOTE: y el grupo de 6 dígitos y entre éste último y la barra... una vez localizados tendrás que montar alguna función que "limpie" esas cadenas.

Comment: Gracias, eso me sirvio de base para definir mi regex final, le agrege solamente que detecte algun que otro espacio. Mi sintaxis final es la siguiente:LOTE:[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]* *[0-9]{6}[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]*\/[^a-z|A-Z|0-9]*[0-9]{1}

Comment: Para detectar un espacio usa "\s", pero en realidad no es necesario, ya lo está haciendo; el bloque [^a-z|A-Z|0-9]* detecta todo lo que no sean letras o números, incluido espacios en blanco.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de @jarios es innecesariamente más complicada, puesto que lo que buscas es simplemente LOTE:[1 o más espacios]123456/7. Basta con que uses:

```
exp_regular = /LOTE:\s+[0-9]{6}\/[0-9]/
```

Si quieres que pueda no haber espacios entre LOTE: y los números, sustituye `\s+` por `\s*` (`+` significa *1 o más*, `*` significa *0 o más*).

Aunque no lo indicas muy claramente, pareces estar buscando el número de lote, así que puedes agrupar esos números:

```
exp_regular = /LOTE:\s+([0-9]{6}\/[0-9])/
```

Una última cosa: dado que esto viene de un OCR, siempre te vas a encontrar mayúsculas, ¿no? No parece buena idea usar `re.IGNORECASE` como mencionas en el enunciado de la pregunta.